# Compile gwt client side code to javascript with Maven

Tags: java, maven, gwt, compilation

before I used **Ant** to builder my app where I compile a JAR (gwt-visualization) to javascript

```
  <target name="compileGWTClient" description="Compile gwt client side code to javascript">
    <echo message="=========== Build gwt"/>
    <java fork="yes" failonerror="true" maxmemory="512M" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.GWTCompiler" classpath="/src:../myproject/tools/lib/gwt-visualization.jar">
      <arg value="-out"/>
      <arg value="build"/>
      <arg value="-style"/>
      <arg value="OBF"/>      
      <arg value="org.compiere.gwt.Compiere"/>
    </java>
   </target>
```

I want to do the same thing with **Maven**

thx

Comment: https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/

There are pretty good examples in the website, and an archetype project you can check out with maven

Comment: I just tested the new one. Here is a step by step example: https://javagc.leponceau.org/2019/01/how-to-use-new-tbroyers-gwt-maven.html

Answer (score 2):

There are two GWT Maven plugins:

- [mojo maven plugin](https://github.com/gwt-maven-plugin/gwt-maven-plugin) (aka. legacy plugin): not recommended anymore, but useful if you use a monolithic maven layout, i.e. projects including client and server code in the same module. Errai project usually uses this monolithic layout and therefore use this plugin.
- [tbroyer maven plugin](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-plugin) (aka. new generation plugin): the recommended one! you must apply the multi-module layout.

More info about the tbroyer plugin (recommended one):

- GitHub: https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-plugin
- Documentation: [https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin](https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/index.html#)
- Multi-module layout archetypes (create new projects): [gwt-maven-archetypes](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes/)

F.e.: here you find a lot of project based on that plugin:  https://github.com/NaluKit/nalu-examples